# Specify '--remote' Heroku app based on git branch

Tags: git, heroku, git-branch

Is it possible to to target an app version in Heroku based on the current Git branch? In the Heroku docs, its specifies how to target a a specific version of the app.

```
# run command on 'production'    
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --remote production
```

> To make things easier, you can use your git config to specify a
>   default app. For example, if you wanted “staging” do be your default
>   remote, you could set it with the following command:
>
> `$ git config heroku.remote staging`

It would make sense to have the local development branch push to the development app and the local production branch push to the production app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Heroku, but you could easily write a shell-script wrapper that would:

- Get the name of the current branch using `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`
- Get the Heroku target by using `git config heroku.<branch>.remote`
- Run the appropriate command

This assumes that you manually configure a per-branch setting for heroku, e.g.:

```
git config heroku.master.remote production
git config heroku.develop.remote staging
```

This doesn't do anything by itself; it's just lets you read these values in a script using `git config`.

Comment: `git config --replace heroku.remote $(git config --get branch.$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD).remote)` sets the remote branch as the heroku remote that is tracking the current branch.

Comment: Yeah, but that resets it persistently, so you need to remember to run this command again every time you switch branches.  You could combine this with a simple shell script (`git-hbranch` or something`) so that you could type `git hbranch <branch>` to both switch branch *and* set `heroku.remote` at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, which would work unless you switched branches in some other way. So its possible, just a little cumbersome. I wasn't sure whether there could be an easier way, but I guess it really isn't that much trouble